# c# ext.net : Insert item in combobox from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs, combobox, ext.net

I want to create a combobox with 2 items. The text of the items should display `DateTime.Now` in different format. The combobox is in row expander. Here is the code of the combo:

```
<ext:ComboBox  runat="server" ID="cmbFormatFFC"   DataIndex="DateFormat"          FieldLabel="Date Format"             Width="400" ForceSelection="true" EmptyText="Select date format...">
      <Listeners>
            <BeforeRender Handler="#{DirectMethods}.fillComboDates()" />
```

and in codebehind:

```
[DirectMethod]
        public void fillComboDates()
        {
            cmbFormatFFC.Items.Insert(0,new Ext.Net.ListItem(DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy"), "d/M/yyyy"));
            cmbFormatFFC.Items.Insert(1,new Ext.Net.ListItem(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), "dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        }
```

But when I expand the row in the application I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'component' of null

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use BeforeRender to load store data. It happens to early in the control life cycle. Your best solution is to use BeforeExpand event on RowExpander. Also, since you have static data in your ComboBox, you want to execute DirectEvent only once. Here is an example:

*.aspx

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="grid" runat="server">
    <ColumnModel>
        <Columns>
            <ext:Column runat="server" DataIndex="Field1" />
        </Columns>
    </ColumnModel>
    <Store>
        <ext:Store runat="server" ID="store">
            <Model>
                <ext:Model runat="server">
                    <Fields>
                        <ext:ModelField Name="Field1" />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:Model>
            </Model>
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
    <Plugins>
        <ext:RowExpander runat="server">
            <Component>
                <ext:ComboBox runat="server" ValueField="Key" DisplayField="Display">
                    <Store>
                        <ext:Store runat="server" ID="comboStore" OnReadData="Store_ReadData">
                            <Model>
                                <ext:Model runat="server">
                                    <Fields>
                                        <ext:ModelField Name="Key" />
                                        <ext:ModelField Name="Display" />
                                    </Fields>
                                </ext:Model>
                            </Model>
                        </ext:Store>
                    </Store>
                </ext:ComboBox>
            </Component>
            <Listeners>
                <BeforeExpand Handler="if (comboStore.getCount() == 0) comboStore.reload();" />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:RowExpander>
    </Plugins>
</ext:GridPanel>
```

*.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack || X.IsAjaxRequest)
        return;

    store.DataSource = new object[] 
    { 
        new { Field1 = "Row 1" },
        new { Field1 = "Row 2" },
        new { Field1 = "Row 3" }
    };

    store.DataBind();
}

protected void Store_ReadData(object sender, StoreReadDataEventArgs e)
{
    comboStore.DataSource = new object[] 
    { 
        new { Key = DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy"), Display = "d/M/yyyy" },
        new { Key = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), Display = "dd-MMM-yyyy" }
    };

    comboStore.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your combo is initialized successfully and your method fillComboDates() is returning values

Comment: why it should return values?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the JS that is being generated and sent to the client by Ext.Net is executing before the `cmbFormatFFC` has been rendered.  To ensure that it happens later, you could change the listener from `BeforeRender` to `BoxReady`.